# My Bluetooth dongle can't find my headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, headset, dongle

I installed ubuntu on my desktop computer recently.
Its version is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS I have a Bluetooth dongle and it can find my cellphone and my laptop Bluetooth properly but it can't find my headset(model: Lenovo HE05) it even doesn't show its name on detected devices
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

I use **lsusb** command to see information about Bluetooth dongle
[image]

Comment: same issue, no idea how to solve

Answer (score 0):

1. Try updating your kernel to a higher version such as 6.5 or above (for me it worked).
2. After this, install `libspa-0.2-bluetooth` with

   ```
   sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
   ```

This package contains a plugin to make Bluetooth audio devices such as speakers and headsets available.

Comment: I upgraded my kernel version to 6.2.0 and installed the libspa-0.2-bluthooth driver but it's the same.